# Looking for command to extract list of AWS security group & their inbound/outbound rules using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, audit

Looking for command to extract list of AWS security group & their inbound/outbound rules using AWS CLI

So far been able to extract the SGs but not with their associated rules. have tried using Powershell for AWS but it returns incomplete results ie not showing all SGs.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If your problem is with code you've written, you should include some of that code (just the parts necessary). Specifically, you should provide relevant parts of your PowerShell (or other) script so that we know what you have done and can maybe someone can help to enhance it, or point you in the right direction.

Comment: aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query "SecurityGroups[*].{Name:GroupName}" --output=text

Comment: But this will only return the security group without their associated rules (inbound/outbound addresses)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call [`describe-security-groups`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html) to obtain a list of Security Groups.

Here is a sample output of one of my security groups:

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "Description": "SSH & Windows",
            "GroupName": "SSHWin-SG",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "73.21.198.65/32"
                        },
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "54.240.123.1/32"
                        },
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "167.129.152.56/32"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                },
                {
                    "FromPort": 3389,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "73.21.198.65/32"
                        },
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "54.240.123.1/32"
                        },
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "167.129.152.56/32"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "ToPort": 3389,
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "123456789012",
            "GroupId": "sg-91cb39d6",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "Ops"
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-7d097214"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `IpPermissions` section returns **inbound** permissions and the `IpPermissionsEgress` section returns **outbound** permissions.

Comment: Thanks so much John, saved me a long time!